# codeigniter inner join not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to do an inner join with codeigniter and i have tried a lot but no success.

Mysql code for inner join,

```
SELECT * FROM shop INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = shop.city_id WHERE city.city_name = 'Bangalore'
```

The above sql query is working perfectly in phpmyadmin. While converting this code in codeigniter it is not working.

Codeigniter code is,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('shop');
$this->db->join('city', 'city.city_id = shop.city_id');
$query = $this->db->where('city', array('city.city_name' => 'Bangalore'));

if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

where am going wrong. am beginner in codeigniter.

Comment: no result is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work well:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('shop');
$this->db->join('city', 'city.city_id = shop.city_id');
//$this->db->where('city', array('city.city_name' => 'Bangalore'));
$this->db->where('city.city_name', 'Bangalore');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
          ->from('shop')
          ->join('city', 'city.city_id = shop.city_id', 'inner')
          ->where('city.city_name', 'Bangalore');
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed to `get()` data from db,

change this to

```
$query = $this->db->where('city', array('city.city_name' => 'Bangalore'));
```

this

```
$this->db->where('city', array('city.city_name' => 'Bangalore'));
$query = $this->db->get();// add this line.
```

No need of `from()` you can use `get()` and pass the table name to it like this.

```
$this->db->select('*');
//$this->db->from('shop');   <-- no need of this line
$this->db->join('city', 'city.city_id = shop.city_id');
$this->db->where('city', array('city.city_name' => 'Bangalore'));
$query = $this->db->get("shop");//<-- give table name here only.
```